# Transfer function of descriptor system $\{\bf A, \bf B, \bf C, \bf D, \bf E\}$ with non-square $\bf A$ and $\bf E$

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Consider the following descriptor system: $\{\bf A, \bf B, \bf C, \bf D, \bf E\}$

With $\bf A \in \mathbb{C}^{\it p \times n}$, $\bf B \in \mathbb{C}^{\it p \times m}$, $\bf C \in \mathbb{C}^{\it l \times n}$, $\bf D \in \mathbb{C}^{\it l \times m}$ and $\bf E \in \mathbb{C}^{\it p \times n}$

if $\bf A$ and $\bf E$ are square matrices, ie. if $p=n$, then the $s$-domain transfer function of this descriptor system is:

$$\textbf{H}(s) = \textbf{C}(s\textbf{E}-\textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{B}+\textbf{D}$$

**My question is:**

> - if $p \ne n$ does that imply that the transfer function does not exist / is "ill defined"? or is there an alternative definition of the transfer function which can be used in that situation?.
> - If the transfer function cannot be defined in this situation then: what can be said about the system? ie. what is the (intuitive) reason for the lack of a well-defined transfer function?.

Comment: If $p\ne n$, your descriptor system is going to be singular, which is not the best property you could get as regularity is much simpler. Would you care sharing more information about your problem to try to understand why you would like to consider such a descriptor system?

Comment: @KBS At the moment I don't actually have a descriptor system with $p \ne n$, this is just a matter of curiosity / wanting to better understand the generalized version of the problem. I am working on some python code which operates on state-space and descriptor systems (I am implementing code for reduced-order macro-modeling for work) and I would like to understand exactly which requirements are necessary and sufficient for each of the operations (such as the transfer-function) to be defined.

Comment: If you are curious about descriptor systems, then I would recommend to consider the case where $n=p$, which is simpler, especially when the pair $(E,A)$ is regular. In that case, you can represent the system in terms of a transfer function, but also in state-space form (which is much more informative) in the Weierstrass form that will emphasize the different system's dynamics. When working such systems it is preferable to work with state-space expressions as they contain all the information about the system.

Comment: The case when $p<n$ and $E$ is full rank is problematic because it does not define uniquely the derivative of the system. On the other hand, when $p>n$, the system may be just simply ill-defined unless the matrices $E$ and $A$ satisfies some properties. If you have very specific questions, ask them, because right now this is too vague. There are literally whole books on descriptor systems.

Comment: @KBS It is not so much that I am "curious about descriptor systems" I am already working extensively with both descriptor and state-space systems for my actual use-cases and I would dare claim that I already have a pretty good handle on both. I was just thinking about the particular case of $p \ne n$ and other generalizations out of curiosity, and wanted to expand my understanding. "There are literally whole books on descriptor systems" I know, and I have read / are reading a bunch of them, but I have not yet seen any references to the transfer function of such systems when $p \ne n$.

Comment: @KBS I disagree that the question is "too vague", I think the question "can (/under which assumptions can) the transfer function be defined for systems with $p \ne n$" is pretty specific. It might be hard to answer in general, but that is not the same as being "vague" IMO.

Comment: I am not here to discuss on the meaning of words. There are extensive lecture notes on the topic as well as books that cover those systems in details. If you have already a pretty good handle on them, then this should not be a problem for you. Here are some references: Duan, "Analysis and design of descriptor linear systems" or the works by Stykel, Benner, Gugercin. etc.

Comment: @KBS Thank you for the references, I do appreciate you chiming in.

Comment: No problem. If there are things you do not understand there, feel free to ask.

Comment: Check “Matrix pencil approach to geometric system theory” by Karcanias, and “On generalized inverses of singular matrix pencils” by Röbenback et al.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks as lot, this looks relevant to my question, I'll have a look at it...

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to answer my own question:

We have:
$$\textbf E\dot x(t)=\textbf Ax(t)+\textbf Bu(t)$$
$$y(t)=\textbf Cx(t)+\textbf Du(t)$$
Laplace transform:
$$s\textbf Ex(s)=\textbf Ax(s)+\textbf Bu(s)$$
$$y(s)=\textbf Cx(s)+\textbf Du(s)$$
Solving for $x(s)$:
$$(s\textbf E-\textbf A)x(s)=\textbf Bu(s)$$
$$x(s) \approx (s\textbf E-\textbf A)^{\dagger}\textbf Bu(s)+\textbf F \textbf Zu(s)$$
Where the columns of $\bf F$ are orthogonal vectors that span the null-space of $s\textbf E-\textbf A$, and $\textbf Z$ is arbitrary.

We then have:
$$y(s)\approx (\textbf C(s\textbf E-\textbf A)^{\dagger}\textbf B+\textbf C\textbf F\textbf Z+\textbf D)u(s)$$
$$\textbf H(s)\approx \textbf C(s\textbf E-\textbf A)^{\dagger}\textbf B+\textbf C\textbf F\textbf Z+\textbf D$$

If the system is fully or under -determined then all the equations hold with an equality sign. If on the other hand the system is fully or over -determined then $\bf F = 0$.

Comment: Yes, this corresponds to one of my comments where I said that it it not uniquely defined when $p<n$ but there is a slight problem as it should not be $Fu(s)$ but a vector that is independent of $u(s)$. It should be $x(s)=(sE-A)^+Bu(s)+(I-(sE-A)^+(sE-A))z(s)$, where $z(s)$ is arbitrary. Note that this solution holds if and only if $(I-(sE-A)(sE-A)^+)Bu(s)=0$ for all $u(s)$. The issue with that is that the state is not uniquely defined, in general, and you end up of with an infinite number of transfer functions.

Comment: @KBS "it should not be Fu(s) but a vector that is independent of u(s)" I'm not sure I agree with that, in the under-determined case the solution of $Ax=b$ is $x=A^{\dagger}b + z$ where $z\in ker(A)$ right?. So defining the solution to $x$ the way I did, with $\textbf Fu(s) \in ker(s\textbf E - \textbf A)$ seems perfectly valid to me.. Perhaps you could show what you believe is the correct solution in an answer?... I agree that of course if the system is under-determined then there are infinitely many possible tf's, however they are all valid tf's for that ss so still it is a valid solution.

Comment: @KBS basically there is nothing wrong with it because you can always define $\textbf Fu(s) = z \in ker(s\textbf E - \textbf A)$, that is just a matter of picking the right $\bf F$.

Comment: Because the vector $z$ in the kernel is independent of $b$. Similarly, the vector in the kernel in the transfer function should be independent of $u(s)$.

Comment: Then your $F$ is depending of your choice for $u(s)$ and the value of $s$. It is not a constant matrix. This is not a convenient formulation.

Comment: @KBS well if I pick the columns of $\bf F$ so that they are orthogonal vectors that are in the null-space of $s\textbf E - \textbf A$ then $\textbf F u(s) \in ker(s\textbf E - \textbf A)$ will be true for any $u(s)$, right?. meaning that $\bf F$ can actually be chosen to be constant and independent on $u(s)$.

Comment: That does not change the issue that $u$ and $z$ are independent. I gave you the exact expression. So, try to equate that with $Fu(s)$ and you will see.

Comment: @KBS I don't see why not. The solution is valid as long as z is in the null-space, so as long as Fu(s) is in the null-space it is a valid solution. That is achieved when the columns of F are orthogonal vectors that are in the null-space. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Because, for the last time, z is a free vector and is indepenpendent of u. In your definition, if you change u you also change z and the latter will not span all the solutions.

Comment: @KBS it won't span all the solutions no, I didn't claim that it would, but it will still be a solution that's all I',m saying.

Comment: Yes, but that is an incomplete solution. The correct formulation is that one which spans all existing solutions.

Comment: @KBS Okay sure that's a fair point, but then can't we just replace Fu(s) with FZu(s) where the columns of F span the null-space of sE-A, then any FZu(s) will be in the null-space of sE-A and thus this formulation spans all the solutions, parameterized by Z.

Comment: No, you still have the issue of independence. The unique solution is the one I gave.

Comment: @KBS Sadly I don't understand how you arrived at that solution, so without any further explanation it won't help me much. And also, x(s) is not independent of u(s) to begin with, so I struggle to see a problem with independence.

Comment: This is the common solution of this type of equations in terms of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. It can be found in standard textbooks. One way to prove the validity is to show that the second term spans the null space of $sE-A$.

Comment: @KBS The text-book I am reading says $x=A^{\dagger}b+z$ with $z\in ker(A)$, I can't see how you would get from there to what you claim is the (only real) solution.

Comment: It is one possible explicit solution to the problem. It is possible to have other equivalent ones but this one is fully explicit.

Comment: @KBS You might be right about that, but I don't see then why my solution would not both 1) be completely valid and 2) span all possible solutions. Again, don't see the problem, but that might well be because there is something I don't know or that I am missing.

Comment: Once again, sit down and write the two solutions on a piece of paper and compare them using all the necessary calculations. It is not by chatting here that you will understand.